# C# .Net How Can I Use Powershell+Exchange Snapin and Make It Stay Open

Tags: c#, powershell

My new code is below, but it says get-mailbox is not recognized like snapin never added.

```
    Runspace runSpace;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.Add("get-mailbox cbilgic");
            pipeline.Invoke();         
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException snapEx = null;
            PSSnapInInfo psinfo = runspaceConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapEx);
        runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig);
        runSpace.Open();
    }
```

Comment: Off topic, but what is the purpose of `out[i]` - looks like you will get an index out of range exception there

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use [Runspaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it will make things much easier.Load your PSSnapin with [RunspaceConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspaceconfiguration%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and get output of your commands with `pipeline.invoke()`. Load the snapin and instantiate the runspace when the form loads, then invoke your commands when the user clicks the button.

Reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) article helped me alot when I was trying similar tasks.

Comment: I did share my new code. It doesnt recognize the snapin. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Post the error you're getting. Also run `Get-PSSnapin -registered` and make sure that exchange tools are registered on your system.